# Wordpress - Customize product icon based on category

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm customizing my screen to list the products, and I would like to put custom icons, the image of this icon I add in the product category.

[image]

And I put the icon in the css as follows:

```
li.product.type-product.product-type-auction .yith-wcact-timeleft-loop div#timer_auction:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url("icon.jpg") no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;float: right;
    margin: 6px 0px 5px 10px;
}
```

But I imagine that I have to do some hook in the function.php, where I can pull the image of the product category that is a child of the 'Icons' category, and then assign this image to my css.

[image]

It is in this space that the white square that I am adding my css appears, but how do I assign the url of the image of the child category of icon that is linked to the product in the background?